# Angular.js - How do I check to see if a string is contained within an array object using a filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, firebase

I'm using Angular and Firebase to create an app that will allow users to post new topics for discussion, as well as vote on existing topics.

When a user is logged in their username is stored in `currentUser.username`. If they've upvoted a topic than their username also appears in `topic.upvotes`.

The problem I'm running into is topic.upvotes is storing an array of values. So if Kenneth and Tyler have both upvoted a topic, `topic.upvotes = {"Kenneth":"Kenneth","Tyler":"Tyler"}`.

All I need to know is if a user has upvoted a topic so that I can apply some conditional CSS to give them visual feedback that they've already voted on that topic.

I've been trying to accomplish this with:

```
ng-class="{user_has_upvoted : signedIn() && topic.upvotes === currentUser.username}"
```

My intent is to apply the `user_has_upvoted` class to the div only if the user is both signed in and they've actually upvoted the topic.

But obviously topic.upvotes (an array) doesn't == or === currentUser.username (a string).

I was hoping there was some way of using some sort of inArry() function, but angular doesn't have anything that I've found that will work.

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Just use `&& topic.upvotes[currentUser.username]`

Comment: That works! /sigh, I've been beating my head against my keyboard for far to long for it to turn out to be that simple. I need a drink of something other than soda! Thanks!

Comment: topic.upvotes is not an array. It's an object with 2 properties.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
ng-class="{user_has_upvoted : signedIn() && topic.upvotes[currentUser.username].localeCompare(currentUser.username) === 0}"
```

Comment: Ian's suggestion above worked like a charm. I'll take a look at localeCompare() as well. Thanks!

Comment: Good it worked . Let me know if you could try with localeCompare

Comment: Maybe one should mention that localeCompare is not implemented in older browsers.